# form data will not go into my database no errors are displayed

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I have insert product category form where you can input a title and description, when I fill the form out my alert message does not work and the data is not inserted into my database, but my window.open command works and it shows the inputs I entered. The file is included into a index.php which has the database connection. Also no errors are displayed.

[image: phpmyadmin]

Note: The below code is all in one file I have just split it up

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_email'])){
    echo "<script>window.open('login.php','_self')</script>";
}else{
?>
```

```html
<div class="row"><!-- row 1 Begin -->
 <div class="col-lg-12"><!-- col-lg-12 Begin -->
  <ol class="breadcrumb"><!--  breadcrumb Begin -->
   <li><!--  li Begin -->
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard / Insert Product Category
   </li><!--  li Finished -->
  </ol><!--  breadcrumb Finished -->
 </div><!-- col-lg-12 Finished -->
</div><!-- row 1 Finished -->
<div class="row"><!-- row 2 Begin -->
 <div class="col-lg-12"><!-- col-lg-12 Begin -->
  <div class="panel panel-default"><!-- panel panel-default Begin -->
   <div class="panel-heading"><!-- panel-heading Begin -->
    <h3 class="panel-title"><!-- panel-title Begin -->
     <i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i> Insert Product Category
    </h3><!-- panel-title Finished -->
   </div><!-- panel-heading Finished -->
   <div class="panel-body"><!-- panel-body Begin -->
    <form action="" class="form-horizontal"><!-- form-horizontal Begin -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-groups Begin -->
      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3"><!-- control-label col-md-3 Begin -->  Product Category Title
      </label><!-- control-label col-md-3 Finished -->
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <input name="p_cat_title" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-groups Finished -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-groups Begin -->
      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3"><!-- control-label col-md-3 Begin -->  Product Category Description
      </label><!-- control-label col-md-3 Finished -->
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <textarea type="text" name="p_cat_desc" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-groups Finished -->
     <div class="form-group"><!-- form-groups Begin -->
      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3"><!-- control-label col-md-3 Begin -->  
      </label><!-- control-label col-md-3 Finished -->
      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
       <input value="Submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
     </div><!-- form-groups Finished -->
    </form><!-- form-horizontal Finished -->
   </div><!-- panel-body Finished -->
  </div><!-- panel panel-default Finished -->
 </div><!-- col-lg-12 Finished -->
</div><!-- row 2 Finished -->
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $p_cat_title = $_POST['p_cat_title'];
    $p_cat_desc = $_POST['p_cat_desc'];
    $insert_p_cat = "insert into product_categories (p_cat_title,p_cat_desc) values ('$p_cat_title,$p_cat_desc')";
    $run_p_cat = mysqli_query($con,$insert_p_cat);
    if ($run_p_cat) {
        echo "<script>alert('Your New Product Category Has Been Added')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php?view_p_cats','_self')</script>";
    }
}?> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: have you tried checking `mysqi_error()` for an error message? ie `$run_p_cat = mysqli_query($con,$insert_p_cat) or die(mysqi_error($con);`

Comment: hint, look at your quotes for `...values ('$p_cat_title,$p_cat_desc')`. You might want to also read up on [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @Sean Thanks for the advise I will look into adding this to my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not specified the method of `<form>` is GET so `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` is false.

You should add method `POST` to your form tag

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
```

Comment: @marcus how about values `('$p_cat_title,$p_cat_desc')";` ?? it should be values `('$p_cat_title','$p_cat_desc')";`

Answer (score 0):

try change  to change

```
('$p_cat_title,$p_cat_desc')
```

to

```
('$p_cat_title','$p_cat_desc')
```

i think you forget to add ' in the end of variable that make only one value got inserted

Comment: If you think that this solves the problem, you should highlight **why** this is the case